# Is there a way Facebook Test User posts with privacy EVERYONE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am writing automated tests for Facebook integration with Facebook Test users feature: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

And I need to test that post is public, but cannot make that because when I set post privacy value to `EVERYONE`, it sets it to `ALL_FRIENDS` and in response I get:

```
{
    "success" => true
}
```

I am using Ruby gem `Koala`, my code looks like this:

```
@test_users = Koala::Facebook::TestUsers.new(:app_id => ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], :secret => ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"])
fb_data = @test_users.create(true, "user_posts,publish_actions")
graph = get_graph(fb_data["access_token"])
graph.put_object("/", "/#{post_id}", privacy: {value: "EVERYONE"}.to_json)
```

It may be unclear, but graph variable contains test user created access_token

Comment: One solution is that I manually create test user and when I log in to his profile change privacy settings, but cmon, there should be automated way of doing that...

Comment: Why do you need to post publicly?

Comment: Because I need.

Comment: And I need to know why